# Is there a way of disassembling a Custom Action written originally in managed code?

Tags: wix

In WiX, when I write a CustomAction in C#, the Visual Studio build first builds a small dll from my C# source code, then combines that small dll with SfxCA.dll, creating the actual file that gets added to the Binary table in the MSI.

Once the MSI has been built, if I extract the Binary object from the MSI and run ildasm on it, disassembly doesn't succeed.

What do I have to do to the Binary custom action object from the MSI so I can disassemble it back to C# source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open your *.CA.dll as cab in 7zip and extract all packaged files. Then use the disassembler of your choice to get the code.